# `du -s .` and `du -hs .` gives different results (on OS X)

Tags: osx, coreutils

The difference with and without `-h` should only be the human readable units, right?

Well apparently no...

```
$ du -s .
74216696    .
$ du -hs .
 35G    .
```

Or maybe I'm mistaken and the result of `du -s .` isn't in KB?

Comment: Try using `du  --block-size=1024 -s .`. Maybe your `BLOCK_SIZE` is set to `512`

Comment: From the (OSX) manual page:  "If BLOCKSIZE is not set, and the -k option is not specified, the block counts will be displayed in 512-byte blocks"

Comment: Which is not super-helpful if the filesystem is actually in 4096-byte blocks.

Comment: So there is no way to have the size in bytes? I thought `-h` was just dividing by 1024 and adding some units

Comment: `echo "74216696*512" | bc` outputs , 37998948352.  And yes, `-h` converts to human readable form by dividing over and over by 1024. What I got was 35.3887 , which is awfully close to what `du` reports. As for size in bytes, just use `--block-size=1`. On Linux, there's `-b` option for that, but I'm not familiar with OS X `du`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`du` without an output format specifier gives disk usage in *blocks* of 512 bytes, not *kilobytes*.  You can use the option `-k` to display in kilobytes instead.  On OS X (or macOS, or MacOS, or Macos; whichever you like), you can customize the default unit by setting the environment variable `BLOCKSIZE` (this affects other commands as well).

Comment: Didn't know that... What's the interest in having the number of blocks? I have never seen one person using _blocks_ when talking about sizes on disk...

Comment: Blocks are the atomic unit of filesystems.  Any file will consume a whole-number of blocks on the disk.  A block may only be partially filled with actual data, but the entire block is allocated to the file.  Most folks' day-to-day usage doesn't care about blocks other than in a percentage-used-versus-free sense.  But low level utilities (e. g. `fdisk`, `df`, and `du`) work in blocks unless directed otherwise because that is the unit by which they count internally.

Comment: @Creak Actually, that part of the answer was wrong. The unit is not the block size of the filesystem. For the purposes of classic Unix commands such as `du`, “block” means 512 bytes. See [file block size - difference between stat and ls](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28780/file-block-size-difference-between-stat-and-ls/28815#28815), [Difference between block size and cluster size](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14409/difference-between-block-size-and-cluster-size/14411#14411)

Comment: *"Any file will consume a whole number of blocks on the disk."*  Well, generally yes—unless your filesystem uses [**tail packing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_suballocation).  But yes, blocks are the basic unit of the filesystem (although the actual block size doesn't necessarily align to the block size used by `du`.)  :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `du` returns the size in number of blocks of 512 bytes.

In order to have the size in KB, you can use the `-k` option that use 1024-byte blocks instead:

```
$ du -ks .                            
43351596    .
$ du -khs .
 41G    .
```