# "stat /etc" size mismatch: 24 blocks, size 8192 instead of 12288

Tags: linux, filesystems, block-device, stat

My `stat /etc` command shows that the number of blocks is 24. I understand that a block here means 512 bytes. So the total size is 24 × 512 which makes it 12288 bytes.

But it shows 8192 bytes instead, and I can't understand why. To my mind it should be 12288 (3 × 4096).

```
$ stat /etc
  File: /etc
  Size: 8192            Blocks: 24         IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 16777345    Links: 152
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2022-01-28 00:03:35.470200471 +0100
Modify: 2022-01-27 23:59:09.331606660 +0100
Change: 2022-01-27 23:59:09.331606660 +0100
 Birth: -
```

`/etc` is on an XFS file system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between block size and cluster size](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14409/difference-between-block-size-and-cluster-size)

Comment: @muru No, that thread doesn't explain why more blocks might be allocated than what the size requires.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is on XFS, the discrepancy between the reported size of `/etc` and the number of blocks allocated to it is probably caused either by preallocation, or by directory shrinking. If you look at your file system with `xfs_db` (`xfs_db -r /dev/...`), you can look at the allocated blocks; for example,

```
$ sudo xfs_db -r ...
xfs_db> inode 16777345
xfs_db> print
[...]
u3.bmx[0-3] = [startoff,startblock,blockcount,extentflag] 
0:[0,1052355,1,0] 
1:[1,1094509,1,0] 
2:[2,1094191,1,0] 
3:[8388608,1052431,1,0]
[...]
```

(The `inode` command above is correct for your system, but your output will differ.)

This is from a directory with a size of 12,288 bytes but an allocated size of 16,384 bytes (32 blocks reported by `stat`). This shows up as three data blocks (start offsets 0, 1, 2), and an extra block (start offset 8388608) which is part of the “freelist”, *i.e.* a block allocated to the directory but not used by the directory’s data.

Comment: I see a similar discrepancy for a few directories on an ext4 filesystem. For ext4, if there are 12 or more blocks then there's an [indirect block](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Direct.2FIndirect_Block_Addressing) (or more but that would be huge for a directory). But I also see an extra block for a few directories that are smaller: e.g. `/etc/alternatives` (it's an Ubuntu system) has 80 half-kB blocks but size 36864. Does this indicate that it used to have ≥12 data blocks, then it shrunk but there's still an indirect block?

Comment: @Gilles that’s interesting, I see the same on a Debian system (`/etc/alternatives` with 96 allocated blocks but a size of 45,056). AFAIK Ext4 doesn’t shrink its directories online, only with `e2fsck -D`); I don’t know what the extra block is there...

Comment: BTW the wiki is no longer the reference for Ext4 file system layout documentation; see https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/ext4/dynamic.html#direct-indirect-block-addressing instead.